# Can't run roundcube

Tags: linux

I installed LAMP and web interface roundcube in Ubuntu 14.04
but apache didn't run, when I type $sudo a2ensite roundcube
apache2 don't run
apache appear:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available# service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server apache2                                                  *
 * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/webmail.example.com/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webmail.tut.tj.conf:19
AH00014: Configuration check failed
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: And your question is...?  (Incidentally, did you *look* at the Apache error log?)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a log directory defined in config, but the directory does not actually exist.

Try the following:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/apache2/webmail.example.com/
chown apache:apache /var/log/apache2/webmail.example.com/
```